# Writing ligatures easily

Tags: keyboard-layout, internationalization

French learners like me come from countries where English(US) keyboard is commonly used. Hence I am using the US Alternative International keyboard on Ubuntu to write accented letters in French. But I have no clue how to write ligatures like œ and æ. I found out some solutions involving a "command" key, which I never found on my keyboard. I would really appreciate the help, since most other answers are vague about the exact key combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ComposeKey sequences to easily write ligatures. This link should provide all the information you need:

http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/compose/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a bunch @Alexandre-w

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Answer (score 0):

From [this official Ubuntu documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey) and some experimentation on my keyboard, I found that Unicode input via `SHIFT CTRL U` and than entering the numeric codes worked for me.

For the letters in question, `SHIFT CTRL U` `0152` gives Œ and `SHIFT CTRL U` `0153` gives œ; `SHIFT CTRL U` `00e6` gives æ, and finally `SHIFT CTRL U` `00c6` gives Æ. For æ and Æ there are simpler alternatives; on my keyboard `ALTGR a` produces æ and `ALTGR A` produces Æ.

Comment: Although you did provide a solution but it's not specific to my inquiry regarding US Alternate International keyboard. Thanks anyway!